# Custom module datasource results - Uncaught ReferenceError: name is not defined

Tags: module

In a custom module we are using the Table class with datasource to retrieve the results of some database entries, as per Expression Engine documentation. We have some filters in our module to filter the results.

This works for the initial view, and when filtering that actually gets some results. but when there are no results we have a console error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: name is not defined
```

where name refers to the first column in our results. I am confiused because we don't even set the columns unless some $data exists.

So I am not sure how to handle no_results when using a datasource filter. Can anyone help? Here is our MCP code for the data.

```
public function index()
{   
    $this->EE->view->cp_page_title =  lang('module_name');

    // Get the submitted search
    $filters = array();
    $filters['search'] = $this->EE->input->post('search');
    $filters['region'] = $this->EE->input->post('region');

    // Set the paramaters
    $custom_params = array(
        'filters' => $filters,
        'num_rows' => 20
    );

    // Set some defaults for the data source
    $default_state = array(
        'sort' => array('id' => 'desc')
    );

    // Get the data from the datasource
    $data = $this->EE->table->datasource('_datasource', $default_state, $custom_params);


    // Create some URLs for the view
    $data['form_action'] = $this->EE->_form_base.AMP.'';
    $data['base_href'] = $this->EE->_base_url;

    // Load view with data
    return $this->EE->load->view('admin/index', $data, TRUE);
}


function _datasource($default_state, $custom_params)
{
    // Get All Data
    $data = $this->EE->data_model->getAll($custom_params['filters']);

    if($data)
    {
        // Set columns
        $columns = array(
            'name'  => array('header' => lang('name')),
            'email'  => array('header' => lang('email')),
            'telephone'  => array('header' => lang('telephone')),
        );
        $this->EE->table->set_columns($columns);

        $offset = $default_state['offset'];
        $this->sort = $default_state['sort'];

        usort($data, array($this, '_sort_rows'));

        return array(
            'rows' => array_slice($data, $offset, $custom_params['num_rows']),
            'no_results' => '<p class="notice">'.lang('no_search_results').'</p>',
            'pagination' => array(
                'per_page'   => $custom_params['num_rows'],
                'total_rows' => count($data),
            ),
            'search' => $custom_params['filters']['search']
        );
    }

}
```

The Javascript used to initiate the filter is:

```
if( $(".searchIndicator").length > 0 )
{
    var indicator = $(".searchIndicator");

    $(".mainTable")
    .table("add_filter", $("#filter"))
    .bind("tableload", function() {
        indicator.css("visibility", "");
    })
    .bind("tableupdate", function() {
        indicator.css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
}
```

Comment: A console error indicates an issue with parsing your (no) results on the front-end...

Comment: Could you post what you're doing with your JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: I will add it to my code above. Javascript documentation is from here https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/cp_javascript/table.html. For info, the Table class is documented here https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/legacy/libraries/table.html.

Comment: This is also occurring with the pagination links EE generates. The first click on a page link works, but subsequent clicks return the above error. The links work when JS is off. But the above Javascript is not related to the pagination. I have no JS for pagination, it uses EE built in code.